# How to change status code of response in grails filter

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm using grails 2.3.7 ; my objective is to forward (not redirect !) all requests that are not ajax to a view 'index.gsp'

I've created a filter :

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

class SinglePageFilters {


  def filters = {
    isNotAjax(uri: '/**') {
        before = {

            if (!request.xhr) {

                render(status:HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, view: 'index')
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This filter works, but the status code of the response is always 404, never 200. It's seems I can't change de the response status code from the filter.

Has someone any hint to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried setting status to `response`? `response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK` before rendering.

Comment: Yes I tried that, and I've the same problem

Comment: I've created a bug report for the grails team : http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11327

Comment: Does index.gsp exists for all the contollers called ? It bother me that you render a view in the "before" interceptor of the filter. According to http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#filterTypes, it is executed before the action. Maybe you should use a forward or a redirect 303 to delegate the response to a specific controller/action.